# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occurring for some users in onRequestPermissions

Tags: java, android

I have an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception happening in my `onRequestPermissionsResult` method, but they are only happening for some users.

These are the permissions I am requesting:

```
private final String [] permissions = {
    "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO",
    "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
};
```

The request (in `onCreate`):

```
int requestCode = 200;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (checkSelfPermission(permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED ||
            checkSelfPermission(permissions[1]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
    }
}
```

The `onRequestPermissionsResult` method:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        recreate();
    }
    else {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.alert_title));
        alertDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.alert_text));
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss());
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're never verifying your request code in `onRequestPermissionResult` so it could be called for a different permission set, maybe internally or by another check you're doing somewhere else?

Comment: @HenryTwist thanks for your answer. No, it is all I'm doing about permissions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is happening only for some users then it is most likely the permission request is getting interrupted. It says in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D)) for `onRequestPermissionResult` that:

> It is possible that the permissions request interaction with the user is interrupted. In this case you will receive empty permissions and results arrays which should be treated as a cancellation.

so the indexing into an empty array will be what's causing your issue.

Therefore I would recommend checking whether the array is empty before checking the result and also make sure to check whether the `requestCode` matches the one you called with. Although this doesn't seem to be the issue here, it seems like a bug waiting to happen.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    if(requestCode != MY_REQUEST_CODE || grantResults.length == 0) return;
```

---

As a side note, the recommended way to do this is no longer using the lifecycle method, but to use the new activity results API with the `RequestPermission` contract, so maybe something to look into.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, friend. I'll try it!